# PyGTK: gtk.TextView.scroll_to_mark doesn't update display for large files

Tags: python, pygtk

My application has a gtk.TextView (actually gtksourceview.View) widget that displays a (large) text file and is indexed by a TreeView. Double-clicking an entry in the TreeView jumps to a corresponding spot in the TextView, which involves this method:

```
def jump_to_line(self, startline):
    itr = self.buffer.get_iter_at_line(startline)
    mark = self.buffer.create_mark(None, itr, True)
    self.scroll_to_mark(mark, 0.0, use_align=True, yalign=0.0)
```

self is my widget, which is a subclass of TreeView, and self.buffer is obviously the corresponding gtk.TextBuffer. startline here is an integer denoting which line to jump to. The issue is that when I test with "large" files (less than 1 MB), this works as expected, but with a "really large" (> 10 MB), the jump doesn't occur until I click on the widget, at which point it updates. I have no idea why it can't scroll automatically for larger files. Is there something I'm not aware of here?

Comment: Interesting: using self.scroll_to_iter works fine. So I'm no longer blocked by the problem, but it's still strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked around by using self.scroll_to_iter.